# CanCan - map controller to existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cancan

I want to "map" `MyController` to `User` model

```
#ability
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    user ||= User.new
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
      can :read, User do |u|
        u && u.user_id == user.id
      end

    end
  end
end

#routes
get 'my_controller/show/(:id)', to: 'MyController#show'

#controller
class MyController < ApplicationController
  # load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    # showing a user
  end
end
```

So `my_controller/show/(:id)` can be accessible only for `admin` and `current user`. For example, the user with `id == 2` can see the their own profile `my_controller/show/2` and cannot others users' ones such as `my_controller/show/1234` unless they are an `admin`.

There is no `My` model in the the project. Ideally, I have to rename `MyController` to `UserController` but I'm not allowed to do that for some reason.

If I uncomment `load_and_authorize_resource` at `MyController`, there will be an error of

```
NameError in MyController#show

uninitialized constant My
```

So how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the name of the type of resource to load and authorize:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
```

Otherwise cancan will attempt to work it out by convention (based on the name of the controller).

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions